# Fonts doesn't load on the first page load

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I developed a website using WordPress, Its in Persian language, I used Persian fonts for loading texts. But on the first page load of web site for a new visitor, fonts doesn't load until visitor clicks on a hyperlink in the website ( http://arjang.ac.ir ).
How can i fix it?

Comment: The font is working for me on first page load.

Comment: In some devices like iPad, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tested in various browsers + iPad and the font loads fine the first time. Are you using an outdated browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).css('font-family', 'font name');
});
```

Comment: There are more than 100 elements which using this specific font name. I cant add font-family to any element of this website using jQuery.